# Circuit required to clean-up an extracted On-OFF-Keying (OOK) Pulse Interval Encoded bit streams

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, rfid

I have a RFID reader that sends an Amplitude Modulated On-Off-Keying (OOK) Pusle Encodede bit stream to a T5577 RFID tag. I am trying to capture the reader to tag communication. To this end, I built a receiver comprising of an AM signal demodulator using of an envelope detector and relevant filters etc using the LM358 OP Amp. The output of the receiver is connected to the Input Capture Pin (ICP1) of an Arduino Nano in order to capture the rising and falling edge timings, log these as a comma separated string to process later (in order to keep the Input Capture ISR routine as short as possible). And cosequently use the logged timings to decode the bits transmitted by the reader. I have set the ATmega Timer1 on the Arduino for 0.5uS per count using 8 prescaler.

Data are transmitted to the tag by interrupting the RF field between reader and tag with short field gaps (On-Off Keying). The time between two gaps encodes the 0/1 information to be transmitted (pulse interval encoding).

The reader transmitted gap duration (time) for the 0 information is between 128uS and 256uS, and that of the 1 information is between 384uS and 512uS. However, the displayed timings on the Arduino Serial Monitor vary from the expected timings of the actual data sent by the reader. At times, a maximun timing of upto 612uS is displayed. I suspect the demodulated data is not a 100% Square wave hence the variation in timing being expirienced.

Question is: Could anyone please suggest a circuit capable of restoring the wave to an 100% square wave without compromising the timing?

Please find the AM demodulator circuit employed.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: AM demodulator circuit]

Comment: I can't see how this would work as a reader - there's no means to transmit the carrier.

Comment: @Karman.... Many thanks for your response. 
It is not a reader. It is a listner or sniffer if you like, to the comunication from reader to tag. In this application, the tag is not present. However, the reader does its thing ie OOK, PIE (evident in Proxmark3 lf t55xx sniff) This is what I have captured, extracted and only need just to clean-up the demodulating data.

Comment: thats what was confusing. your circuit is for a reader, not a sniffer. It doesn't make sense to pass current through the coil. fix up your circuit so you get better signal then you can just use a slicer to recover the data.

Comment: @Kartman..... The circuit diagram has been edited. The actual circuit used is currently displayed. I suppose 1/2 the 358 does the slicing. If not could you please suggest a slicer circuit?

Comment: Start with an AGC amplifier front end to normalize Tx,Rx levels then a BPF with low Q then AGC again, then a Schottky diode , then use LPF and a comparator with hysteresis

Comment: @Tony Stewart Many thanks for your response. Do you have a particular circuit example to share? Also, could you please define terms: 1. BPF 2. LPF. Thanks

Comment: **B**and-**P**ass **F**ilter ... **L**ow-**P**ass **F**ilter

Comment: @ Tony Stewart: Would the LPF be required? I ask this because the receiver should be an OOK receiver. To this end, there is really no modulating signal. I suppose that the 125 kHz carrier is keyed on and off at timed intervals to send the 0/1 information.